# Essential list of the top-ten most representative Italian literary works ever

Tags: vocabulary, resources

I would like to make an essential list of the top-ten most representative Italian literary works ever, something like a *Canon of Italian Literature* (or *Italian books everyone should read at least once in their lifetime*). The works should be representative of Italian language

1. throughout the centuries
2. across literary genres
3. across geographic areas

The list should be as objective as possible, i.e. it should be based on *solid historical foundations*, not just personal taste.

For example, the list would not be well-balanced if ten works by the same author were provided, or ten written in the same century or ten belonging to the same literary genre or ten written by authors from the same geographic area. Analogously, the list would not be good if it neglected historically illustrious authors or glorious masterpieces in favour of minor authors or works, or authors or works touched by short-lived glory.

Each work in the list should have the format

> [name and surname of author]. [year]. *[title]*.

and sorted in chronological order.

My list could be something like this:

1. Dante Alighieri. 1321. *Divina Commedia*.
2. Giovanni Boccaccio. 1351/1353. *Decameron*.
3. Francesco Petrarca. 1374. *Canzoniere*.
4. Niccolò Machiavelli. 1513. *Il Principe*.
5. Ludovico Ariosto. 1532. *Orlando Furioso*.
6. Ugo Foscolo. 1802. *Le ultime lettere di Jacopo Ortis*.
7. Giacomo Leopardi. 1837. *Canti*.
8. Alessandro Manzoni. 1842. *I Promessi Sposi*.
9. Luigi Pirandello. 1904. *Il fu Mattia Pascal*.
10. Umberto Eco. 1980. *Il nome della rosa*.

This is just an example and, although it reflects pretty well the criteria above, it also comes with some major drawbacks: it is entirely focused towards the past; contemporary Italian is virtually missing; it is not sufficiently representative of Italian areas; not a single female author is in there (in my opinion Grazia Deledda's *Canne al vento* is no match compared to others in the list and many other candidates).

For the reasons above, feel free to propose your own lists.

P.S. [Apparently](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/alessandro-manzoni/) *I Promessi Sposi* was edited between 1840 and 1842 (after *la risciacquatura in Arno*, known as *edizione quarantana*).

---

I have found a [Canon of 137 Italian literary works from Italian Wikisource](http://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Wikisource:Canone_delle_opere_della_letteratura_italiana). Seems **very authoritative**. More details in the [talk page](http://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Discussioni_Wikisource:Canone_delle_opere_della_letteratura_italiana).

Comment: Never heard about `Grabriele D'Annunzio`, but he might have been a big writer. In my opinion, you should have another writer of the seventieth or eighteenth century, since you have no one.

Comment: Io lascerei fuori D'Annunzio proprio perché lo conosco. Direi che, piaccia o meno, non sia possibile escludere le rime del Petrarca, quanto meno per l'influenza che hanno avuto sul resto della letteratura italiana e no. (Per quanto riguarda il Seicento menzionato più su, personalmente ho un debole per Marino e il suo *Adone*...)

Comment: Diciamo che toglierei lo *Jacopo Ortis* (tanto, se qualcuno fa lo stesso per la letteratura tedesca, si trova lì l'originale) e D'Annunzio, e inserirei quanto meno le rime di Petrarca e la *Gerusalemme Liberata*. Sul *Nome della rosa*, per quanto personalmente apprezzi Eco, ho qualche perplessità: è tutt'altro che “representative of Italian language” del 1980.

Comment: L'ultima edizione dei *Promessi sposi* non è del 1840?

Comment: @Charo: including an author "to have at least one woman" would break the criteria established in the OP, by including a work for reasons other than being "representative of the human language" - and paradoxically, it would be a sexist behaviour, because it would value women based on their gender rather than their merits.
Just my two cents.

Comment: Due contemporanei che giocano con molta intelligenza con la lingua italiana sono Benni e Bergonzoni.

Comment: nessun settecentesco? (per Quattrocento e Seicento capisco l'esclusione, anche se forse il *Dialogo sui massimi sistemi* avrebbe senso)

Comment: @randomatlabuser Quel canone sembra promettente, ma la pagina di Talk relativa è delirante e piena di punti esclamativi e di allusioni interne. Ma soprattutto non è chiara una cosa: quelle 137 opere sono tutte e sole quelle elencate da Asor Rosa? Qualcuno che ha accesso a *La Letteratura Italiana – Le Opere* (Einaudi, 1992) può controllare? Peraltro, nella tabella compaiono 163 opere...

Comment: @DaG I contenuti della Wikimedia Foundation sono di norma molto inaffidabili, non sono in grado di controllare se abbiano fatto pasticci. La fonte originaria (Asor Rosa), _quella_ mi sembra molto autorevole: solo per questo ho pensato fosse utile aggiungere un link (sperando che la pagina di Wikisource venga gestita in maniera la meno inaffidabile possibile, ma questa è appunto cosa che non sono in grado di controllare).

Answer (score 2):

Due to the difficulty to make the list, I propose here lots of candidates. Feel free to add more.

1. Francesco d’Assisi. 1224. *Il Cantico di Frate Sole*.
2. Cielo d'Alcamo. 1231-1250. *Contrasto*.
3. Anonimo fiorentino. 12?. *Novellino*.
4. Marco Polo. 1298. *Il Milione*
5. Dante Alighieri. 1321. *Divina Commedia*.
6. Giovanni Boccaccio. 1351/1353. *Decameron*.
7. Francesco Petrarca. 1374. *Canzoniere*.
8. Anonimo. 1476. *I fioretti di san Francesco*.
9. Niccolò Machiavelli. 1513. *Il Principe*.
10. Pietro Aretino. 1524. *Sonetti lussuriosi*.
11. Ludovico Ariosto. 1532. *Orlando Furioso*.
12. Anonimo. 15?. *La Venexiana*.
13. Annibal Caro. 1566. *Eneide*.
14. Torquato Tasso. 1575. *Gerusalemme liberata*
15. Giordano Bruno. 1584. *La Cena de le Ceneri*.
16. Giulio Cesare Croce. 1602. *Le sottilissime astuzie di Bertoldo*.
17. Tommaso Campanella. 1623. *La città del Sole*.
18. Giovan Battista Marino. 1623. *Adone*.
19. Galileo Galilei. 1630. *Dialogo sopra i due massimi sistemi del mondo*.
20. Giuseppe Berneri. 1695. *Meo Patacca*.
21. Carlo Goldoni. 1751. *La locandiera*.
22. Cesare Beccaria. 1764. *Dei delitti e delle pene*.
23. Giuseppe Parini. 1765. *Il giorno*.
24. Vittorio Alfieri. 1782. *Saul*.
25. Giuseppe Parini. 1790. *Odi*.
26. Ugo Foscolo. 1802. *Le ultime lettere di Jacopo Ortis*.
27. Ippolito Pindemonte. 1822. *Odissea*.
28. Vincenzo Monti. 1825. *Iliade*
29. Ugo Foscolo. 1827. *Poesie e carmi*.
30. Giacomo Leopardi. 1832. *Zibaldone di pensieri*.
31. Giacomo Leopardi. 1837. *Canti*.
32. Alessandro Manzoni. 1842. *I Promessi Sposi*.
33. Ippolito Nievo. 1858. *Le confessioni di un italiano*.
34. Giuseppe Gioachino Belli. 1863. *Sonetti romaneschi*.
35. Carlo Collodi. 1881. *Le avventure di Pinocchio. Storia di un burattino*.
36. Giovanni Verga. 1881. *I Malavoglia*.
37. Emilio Salgàri. 1884. *Le tigri di Mompracem*.
38. Gabriele D'Annunzio. 1888. *Il piacere*.
39. Edmondo De Amicis. 1886. *Cuore*.
40. Giovanni Verga. 1888. *Mastro Don Gesualdo*.
41. Italo Svevo. 1892. *Una vita*.
42. Federico De Roberto. 1893. *I Viceré*.
43. Antonio Fogazzaro. 1895. *Piccolo mondo antico*.
44. Emilio Salgàri. 1898. *Il Corsaro Nero*.
45. Italo Svevo. 1898. *Senilità*.
46. Giosuè Carducci. 1901. *Poesie*.
47. Giovanni Pascoli. 1903. *Myricae*.
48. Luigi Pirandello. 1904. *Il fu Mattia Pascal*.
49. Luigi Pirandello. 1908. *L'umorismo*.
50. Vamba. 1908. *Il giornalino di Gian Burrasca*.
51. Grazia Deledda. 1913. *Canne al vento*.
52. Federigo Tozzi. 1919. *Con gli occhi chiusi*.
53. Luigi Pirandello. 1921. *Sei personaggi in cerca d'autore*.
54. Italo Svevo. 1923. *La coscienza di Zeno*.
55. Luigi Pirandello. 1926. *Uno, nessuno e centomila*.
56. Alberto Moravia. 1929. *Gli indifferenti*.
57. Ignazio Silone. 1933. *Fontamara*.
58. Luigi Pirandello. 1936. *Novelle per un anno*.
59. Dino Buzzati. 1940. *Il deserto dei Tartari*.
60. Carlo Levi. 1944. *Cristo si è fermato ad Eboli*
61. Elio Vittorini. 1944. *Uomini e no*.
62. Carlo Emilio Gadda. 1946. *Quer pasticciaccio brutto de via Merulana*.
63. Primo Levi. 1947. *Se questo è un uomo*.
64. Cesare Pavese. 1948. *La casa in collina*.
65. Cesare Pavese. 1949. *La luna e i falò*
66. Vasco Pratolini. 1952. *Metello*.
67. Alberto Moravia. 1954. *Racconti romani*.
68. Pier Paolo Pasolini. 1955. *Ragazzi di vita*.
69. Italo Calvino. 1957. *Il barone rampante*.
70. Elsa Morante. 1957. *L'isola di Arturo*.
71. Giuseppe Tomasi di Lampedusa. 1957. *Il Gattopardo*.
72. Carlo Cassola. 1959. *La ragazza di Bube*.
73. Leonardo Sciascia. 1961. *Il giorno della civetta*.
74. Giorgio Bassani. 1962. *Il giardino dei Finzi-Contini*.
75. Primo Levi. 1962. *La tregua*.
76. Italo Calvino. 1963. *Marcovaldo*.
77. Beppe Fenoglio. 1963. *Il partigiano Johnny*.
78. Beppe Fenoglio. 1963. *Una questione privata*.
79. Natalia Ginzburg. 1963. *Lessico famigliare*.
80. Italo Calvino. 1964. *Il sentiero dei nidi di ragno*.
81. Dino Buzzati. 1968. *La boutique del mistero*.
82. Italo Calvino. 1972. *Le città invisibili*.
83. Gianni Rodari. 1972. *Filastrocche in cielo e in terra*.
84. Conferenza Episcopale Italiana. 1973. *La sacra Bibbia*.
85. Elsa Morante. 1974. *La storia*.
86. Primo Levi. 1975. *Il sistema periodico*.
87. Italo Calvino. 1979. *Se una notte d'inverno un viaggiatore*.
88. Oriana Fallaci. 1979. *Un uomo*.
89. Umberto Eco. 1980. *Il nome della rosa*.
90. Primo Levi. 1982. *Se non ora quando?*.
91. Stefano Benni. 1983. *Terra!*.
92. Italo Calvino. 1983. *Palomar*.
93. Primo Levi. 1986. *I sommersi e i salvati*.
94. Umberto Eco. 1988. *Il pendolo di Foucault*.
95. Oriana Fallaci. 1990. Insciallah_.
96. Alessandro Baricco. 1993. *Oceano mare*.
97. Antonio Tabucchi. 1994. *Sostiene Pereira*.
98. Umberto Eco. 2000. *Baudolino*.
99. Margaret Mazzantini. 2001. *Non ti muovere*.
100. Tiziano Terzani. 2004. *La fine è il mio inizio*.

Comment: Hi, if I may..what is the purpose of making the suggested list?..I mean, it is going to be an opinion-based issue, though an interesting one.

Comment: @Josh61, I agree the question is open to different [subjective answers](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). However the criteria set some strict constraints to avoid arbitrary answers and require answers to be constructive and justifiable on the basis of the history of Italian literature. In my opinion lists are useful for a variety of reasons: if you have a budget to spend on Italian books, which books would you purchase so that your collection would represent Italian language at its very best, with its history, variety, etc.?

Comment: What is really difficult is to choose only ten works.

Comment: A questa lista, io aggiungerei *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo (Montale diceva che era il racconto perfetto) e *Mistero buffo* di Dario Fo (per alcuna ragione ha vinto il premio Nobel di letteratura).